# How to setup a MAX Audio output level for BlueTooth Headphones

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, headphones

Long story short, I bought non-Apple branded headphones, the headphones have some code to auto move the volume to about 75% every time I turn them on, rather than the probably ~10% I prefer to have them at and turn the headphones off at.

Apple does not provide a max bluetooth volume setting as far as I've researched.

I'd like a simple code to perhaps hook into default bluetooth handling, and ensure the volume is at my preferred ~10% volume when about to play.

I've posted on ios forms asking for Apple to add a very SIMPLE setting of max bluetooth volume, and I've seen many others on the Apple forms have annoyingly difficult times with their bluetooth headsets being too loud on connect. It seems Apple won't fix the problem, as it's not *their* branded bluetooth headset.

But, it's assaulting my ears every time I forget to decrease the volume before playing a video/music after connecting. I'm hoping an ios savy person knows a way to hook into the bluetooth or playback start, to ensure volume is low enough (ideally readjusting it lower) to be comfortable on playback start.

It certainly wouldn't be complicated code. Maybe someone savy with IOS knows a way? I am a software developer, but not generally for IOS stuff, but I should be able to follow any code you can help with.

ChatGPT gave me this response, which seems wrong (regarding not being able to programmatically change the volume) as my headphones *are* increasing the volume, so I think I should be able to programmatically decrease them in something like this script and perhaps correct permissions (or, maybe the headphones are *not* increasing the volume and it's just IOS handling my headphones in an inappropriate way - making the volume way too loud - so that I buy their Apple branded products?), ChatGPT said:

To achieve this functionality in iOS, you would typically use CoreBluetooth framework to detect when Bluetooth is about to be used and AVFoundation framework to control the volume. However, it's important to note that directly manipulating the volume programmatically is not possible on iOS due to privacy and security restrictions imposed by Apple. Users have to manually set the volume on their devices.

However, you can alert the user or suggest lowering the volume programmatically when a Bluetooth device connects. Here's a conceptual example of how you might implement this:

swift:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let bluetoothManager = CBCentralManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        bluetoothManager.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            // Scan for Bluetooth devices
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        // Check if the discovered peripheral is a Bluetooth device you're interested in
        // For demonstration, let's say your Bluetooth device has a specific name
        if peripheral.name == "YourBluetoothDeviceName" {
            // Alert the user or suggest lowering the volume
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Bluetooth Device Connected", message: "Please ensure the volume is low for your safety.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

In this example:

We're creating a CBCentralManager instance to manage Bluetooth interactions.
In centralManagerDidUpdateState, we're checking if Bluetooth is powered on and then initiating a scan for peripherals.
In didDiscover, we're checking if the discovered peripheral matches the one you're interested in. If so, we're presenting an alert to the user, suggesting that they lower the volume for safety reasons.
Remember, you cannot programmatically adjust the device volume directly due to iOS restrictions. You can only prompt the user to do so.